# For combinations of GROUP BY dimensions where no results exist, how can I return those results anyway with just "0" as the count?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Say I have a table that looks like this:

| membership_id | service | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | monthly |
| 2 | A | quarterly |
| 3 | A | yearly |
| 4 | A | monthly |
| 5 | A | quarterly |
| 6 | A | yearly |
| 7 | B | monthly |
| 8 | B | monthly |
| 9 | B | monthly |

The query

```
select 
service, frequency, count(membership_id)
from table
group by service, frequency
```

will yield these results:

| service | frequency | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | monthly | 2 |
| A | quarterly | 2 |
| A | yearly | 2 |
| B | monthly | 3 |

Is there a way to return ALL combinations of group-by dimensions, and return "0" where there is no results? Like so:

| service | frequency | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | monthly | 2 |
| A | quarterly | 2 |
| A | yearly | 2 |
| B | monthly | 3 |
| B | quarterly | 0 |
| B | yearly | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cross join to give you every possible combination of service and frequency, and then left join to that in order to count non-null membership id's.

```
with cte AS (
    select distinct a.service, b.*
    from table a

    cross join (
    select frequency
    from table
        ) b
)

select

a.service, 
a.frequency, 
count(membership_id)

from cte a

left join table b
    ON a.service = b.service
    and a.frequency = b.frequency

group by 1,2

order by a.service, a.frequency
```